# Get the first three digits of a five digit number

Tags: ruby

```
tickets = (0..99999).to_a.sample(5)
```

This creates five different winning lottery numbers.  Each one has five digits.

One of the prizes is if you have the first 3 digits in the winning number, you win.  I'm using this to get the first three digits of a the first winning number:

```
tickets[0].to_s[0..2].to_s
```

The problem is if the number is 342, this returns "342" instead of "003."

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [String#rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) function:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > 342.to_s.rjust(5, "0")
 => "00342"
```